# How to connect/ authenticate a azure devops pipeline to artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am able to "deploy" from my local machine to Azure Artifacts using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/publish-maven-artifacts?view=azure-devops) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops).
In first link it tells to just change goal from `package` to `deploy` in the pipeline.
The problem is that the pipeline

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'deploy'
```

is failing with 401, because the server settings are missing with the credentials.

How it is supposed to work from devops pipeline? I would like to not use a personal account.
But i can create a token for my account but where to put? where to change/ put settings.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the task [MavenAuthenticate@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/maven-authenticate-v0?view=azure-pipelines) to provide credentials for Azure Artifacts feeds and external Maven repositories.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: 'xxx'
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'demo/pom.xml'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

And then make sure the service account of the pipeline has permission:

[Authorization Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope)

[image]

Comment: thanks! - in my case the authenticate is green and error changed from 401 to 403. but this is permission problem as you pointed out (will solve it).

Comment: @BBowman-Zhu-MSFT i set the scope but didn't help. can you tell what permission to set on the feed?